# Wifi Issues on Lenovo Flex 6 14" (But rebooting to Windows and back fixes it temporarily!)

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, network-manager, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Flex 6 14" laptop with a Realtek 8822be wifi card. Whenever I first loaded Ubuntu, my wifi worked fine. However, on subsequent boots, it would not show any access points available (not just my network, but none of my neighbor's networks showed up either). Sometimes, reboots fixed the problem, other times, it didn't. After some experimentation, it seems that rebooting to Windows and back temporarily fixes the problem.

The problem doesn't seem like it is a bad driver, as it works sometimes. I tried changing the `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` to set `wifi.powersave` to 2 from its default value of 3, but that did nothing. Changing it to 1 allowed wifi to persist through reboots from Ubuntu, but if I power off the laptop, then start it up again, the wifi will not work unless I boot Windows again.

Any ideas?